# Design Pattern for metadata search panel

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

My question is about exploring the right design pattern for our dynamic meta data search panel component.

We are developing a java based web application to capture meta data for dynamic custom objects. Basically there would be one base object having attributes like creator (i.e. user), creation date, status etc. There would be child objects of this main object. The child objetcs define the type of object say Vehicles or Buildings etc. These child objects would have dynamic grand children object(s) - each grandchildren object having it's own custom schema for metadata.

We would like to store these objects into document based databases like MongoDB and perform search against the same. We would like to do the search panel component design in a way that the implementation does not change when we add and search new Object types or grand children objects into the document database in future. We would also like to ensure that the search panel has a uniform UI across different dynamic objects.

I need suggestions on what desing pattern can I use here.

Comment: If you can post just a shred of pseudocode/code, that would really help.